# Vim: go to beginning or end of the visual area

Tags: vim, hotkeys, keymap

I want to do some tricky mappings that wraps currently selected visual area with some code.
In order to do that I need to make sure that I am at the beginning of the current visual area.
Is there any hotkey for that in visual mode?

Comment: You mean like "I" or "0" ?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might consider integrating surround.vim into your solution -- could save lots of effort, since it already provides this functionality. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might be able to use

```
`<
```

and

```
`>
```

The tricky bit is that they go to the start/end of the *previous* visual area, not the current one.

So, you could do something like this:

```
:vmap __ <Esc>`>aEND<Esc>`<iSTART<Esc>l
```

In my version of Vim, after using that sequence, the last visual area is slightly wonky (re-selecting it with `gv` selects an area that is not quite right).

To move around in the *current* visual area a user can use `o` (and maybe `O` if using a block area) interactively, but these are not deterministic if you want to use them in a map.

So, I wrote the function below to make a deterministic version of `o` (defined as `_^` and `_$` below). The example `_*` command uses them to do a similar ‘wrapping’ as the above `__`, but also fakes keeping the visual area selected by re-selecting an area (`1v`) after doing the wrapping:

```
:function! MoveToVisualAreaExtrema(wantEnd) range
:  normal gv
:  let l:mode = mode()
:  " only character (v) and line mode (V) work with this implementation
:  if !(l:mode == 'v' || l:mode == 'V')
:    throw 'must be in character- or line-visual mode'
:  endif
:  " get original posision
:  let l:iLn = line('.')
:  let l:iCl = col('.')
:  " move to other end of visual selection
:  normal o
:  " get current position
:  let l:cLn = line('.')
:  let l:cCl = col('.')
:  let l:atEnd = (l:cLn > l:iLn) || (l:cLn == l:iLn) && (l:cCl > l:iCl)
:  if a:wantEnd != l:atEnd
:    normal o
:  endif
:  if l:mode == 'V'
:    execute 'normal ' . (a:wantEnd ? '$' : '0')
:  endif
:endfunction
:vmap _^ :call MoveToVisualAreaExtrema(0)<CR>
:vmap _$ :call MoveToVisualAreaExtrema(1)<CR>

:" Example: wrap ";print q();" around the visual region
:vmap _* _$<Esc>a);<Esc>gv_^<Esc>i;print q(<Esc>l1v
```

Answer (score 0):

Capital H ("Home") will take you to the beginning, and "L" ("Last") to the end.

One bit of behaviour that might cause you trouble is that these put the cursor on the first non-blank character of the line, so type "0" to go to the absolute start of line.